# Github known hosts issue. Warning appears on random commands

Tags: linux, git, ssh

I'm a little suspicious that this comes up when I am running a very simple python script with "python3 main.py" that doesn't do any network accessing, it just computes some numbers and exits.

"Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'github.com' differs from the key for the IP address '140.82.114.4'
Offending key for IP in /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:3
Matching host key in /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:50
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?"

I guess there are two parts to this question:

i) Why does this occur on commands that seemingly have nothing to do with git or github.

ii) How can I trace what is making the request to github when I run my command?

I have tried removing the known hosts manually by the line number and with ssh-keygen -R github.com. The error reappears. If I respond to the prompt it silences it for a small amount of time.

This occurs on random commands.

Comment: can you share the python script? That does seem very suspicious

Comment: The script is in this repository I've just made public: https://github.com/DanNicolau/bar-build-optimizer. I don't import any modules that are not in the base python libraries and I've written it all myself so I doubt the contents are relevant. Can probably assume this is just a hello world.

Comment: I just got it on an ls command too!

Comment: its a recent change that github made since the old host was leaked. I got the same message about a month ago i think, I updated the host to the new one. Theres an article here: https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/

Comment: he uses github in other folders, since its installed globally it can cause the error messages each time he uses the terminal. I am sure I have seen this type error message myself in the past.

Comment: Did you read through this? https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/27405

Comment: Followed the steps on the first article linked, added new keys, still got the issue with previous entries which were known by an ip address. Removed the offending ip as well from known hosts, not getting the issue but I'll give it a bit to be sure. Manually checked fingerprints just to be sure I got the right ones.

Also looked through ps auxwww, nothing there that I didn't expect to see.

Comment: Still getting the issue, and for some reason its the same ip address even though I've ran ssh-keygen -R "140.82.114.4". Considering removing all known hosts except for the github keys I've just added.

I am also using https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt, I will uninstall to see if this resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i) Was using https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt which was accessing git and using old keys from github that were updated around March, thanks to @Raie for letting me know.

Remove old offending github keys by the ip and hostname, then get new ones using instructions [github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key](https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key)

Completely uninstall bash-git-prompt and reinstall it.

ii) Can use ps auxwww to see running processes and see if any should (or shouldnt) be accessing git while the prompt is open.